# How objects are created when the prototype of their constructor isn't an object?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I answered this question: [How do objects created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822188/how-do-objects-created/41843666#41843666)
but I also have a question after I answered it.

```js
function Bar() {
    this.foo = true;
}
console.log('obj3');
Bar.prototype = 3;
var obj3 = new Bar();
console.log(obj3);
console.log(obj3.constructor === Bar);
console.log(obj3.constructor === Object);
  
console.log(Object.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj3));
console.log(obj3.foo);
```

`Bar.prototype = 3`, my theory is that, when `new Bar()` executed, as in **Step 2**, the created object is supposed to linked to `Bar.prototype`, but since the value of `Bar.prototype` doesn't refer to an object, implicitly a default value was assigned, which is the `Object.prototype`.

Due to `object.prototype.constructor`'s reference to the `Object`, `obj3.constructor` also refer to the `Object`, but `obj3`'s *de facto* constructor is still `Bar`, because of **Step 1**, which also can be proved by `console.log(obj3.foo); // true`.

Am I right?

@Leo asked me if I could provide more information about the internal mechanism. He had tested it in Firefox Chrome Safari, they all behave the same, he thinks it should be something clearly specified in ECMA-262. However, he hasn't got to the right place. But I didn't find anything to support my argument too, therefore I'm looking for your help. Could you provide more information about the internal mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is specified in [GetPrototypeFromConstructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-getprototypefromconstructor):

> 3. Let *proto* be ? [Get](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-get-o-p)(*constructor*, `"prototype"`).
> 4. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*proto*) is not Object, then
>
>    1. Let *realm* be ? [GetFunctionRealm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-getfunctionrealm)(*constructor*).
>    2. Let *proto* be realm's intrinsic object named *intrinsicDefaultProto*.

Specifically, it works like this:

1. `new Bar()` calls `Bar.[[Construct]]`
2. That initializes the *thisArgument* using
   [OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor)(*newTarget*, `"%ObjectPrototype%"`)
3. That returns an object which inherits from
   [GetPrototypeFromConstructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-getprototypefromconstructor)(*constructor*, *intrinsicDefaultProto*)

So if the `prototype`is not an object, the default will be the %ObjectPrototype% of that realm.

Note that it's not always `Object.prototype`:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var win = iframe.contentWindow;
document.body.removeChild(iframe);
var F = win.Function("")
F.prototype = 5;
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(new F());
proto === Object.prototype; // false
proto === win.Object.prototype; // true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. In the beginning I thought `obj3.constructor` is `Number` as if `3` is boxed to its object form, but it's not. Then I started to search in the spec. Honestly the spec is quite difficult to read. Thanks again.

Comment: @Leo I guess boxing the number could make sense, but when should that happen? If each instantiation generates a different object, all instances will inherit from different objects! It could happen when you set `prototype`, but that would require some kind of setter, which didn't exist in ES1.

Comment: I've learned a lot from your answer, very impressive, thank you!